# Reconciling two characterizations of symplectic potential

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, symplectic-geometry

The reference text is N.M.J. Woodhouse's *Geometric Quantization*.

Let $Q$ be a smooth manifold with coordinates $\{q_i\}$, and $M=T^*Q$ be its cotangent bundle with coordinates $(p_i, q_i)$ (so that $\{p_i\}$ will characterize a covector).

It has been stated that, for the 1-form $\theta = p_adq^a, \omega=d\theta$ is a symplectic form on $M$ ($\omega=dp^a\wedge dq_a-$note that I'm using the Einstein summation convention). So far, I'm on board with things.

But now, in order to show that $\theta$ is coordinate-independent, it has been characterized in the following alternative manner:

$\theta_{(p, q)}:=(X_{(p, q)}\mapsto p(\pi_*X_{(p, q)}))$, where $X\in\chi(M), \pi_*$ is the pushforward of the projection $(p, q)\mapsto q$.

I'm unable to figure out how these two are equivalent. I suppose that in particular, what needs to be shown is that $p_adq^a(p, q)(X)=p(\pi_*X)$. Any help on the matter?

Comment: Figure out how to explicitly write a tangent vector $X\in T_{(p,q)}T^*Q$, what $d\pi$ does with such a tangent vector, and you should be able to see how the pieces fit together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I need to practice that myself I'd like to give it a go:

- The vector field $X$ can be written as
  \begin{align}
  X&=u^a\partial_{p_a}+v^a\partial_{q_a}\,,\\[2mm]
  \end{align}
  with functions $u^a,v^a$ on $M$ (i.e. functions "of" $\{p_i,q_i\}$)
- For any differentiable function $f$ on $M\,,$ we see from $\pi:(p,q)\mapsto q$
  that
  \begin{align}\tag{1}
  (\pi_*X)(f)&:=X(f\circ\pi)=(v^a\partial_{q_a}f)\,.
  \end{align}
  To see this note that by definition of the projection $(f\circ\pi)(p,q)=f(q)\,.$ Therefore, the LHS of (1) does nothing else than applying $X$ to $f$
  which depends only on $q_1,...,q_n\,.$

In short: (1) is
\begin{align}
\pi_*X&=v^a\partial_{q_a}\in TQ\,.
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
\theta(\pi_*X)=(p_b\,dq^b)(v^a\partial_{q_a})&=p_av^a\,.
\end{align}
Since I don't have the book I assume that the authors identify $p_av^a$ with $p(v^a\partial_{q_a})\,.$

Comment: $X(f\circ\pi)=(v^a\partial_{q_a}f)$: Could you explain this step? Thanks!

Comment: Done. Like a lot of stuff in DG, pushforward and pullback is nothing else than chain rule. In this case it is almost trivial despite the intimidating notation.